# Why do i get this error - MATLAB

Tags: vector, matlab

I have the image and the vector

```
a = imread('Lena.tiff');
v = [0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25];
```

and this M-file

```
function y = Funks(I, gama, c)
[m n] = size(I);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        J(i, j) = (I(i, j) ^ gama) * c;
    end
end
y = J;
imshow(y);
```

when I'm trying to do this:

```
f = Funks(a,v,2)
```

I am getting this error:

```
??? Error using ==> mpower
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in ==> Funks at 5
        J(i, j) = (I(i, j) ^ gama) * c;
```

Can anybody help me, with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because you're trying to raise a number to a vector power. Translated (i.e. replacing formal arguments with actual arguments in the function call), it would be something like:

```
J(i, j) = (a(i, j) ^ [0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25]) * 2
```

Element-wise power `.^` won't work either, because you'll try to "stuck" a vector into a scalar container.

**Later edit:** If you want to apply each gamma to your image, maybe this loop is more intuitive (though not the most efficient):

```
a = imread('Lena.tiff');        % Pics or GTFO
v = [0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25];   % Gamma (ar)ray -- this will burn any picture

f = cell(1, numel(v));  % Prepare container for your results

for k=1:numel(v)
    f{k} = Funks(a, v(k), 2);  % Save result from your function
end;
% (Afterwards you use cell array f for further processing)
```

Or you may take a look at the other (more efficient if maybe not clearer) solutions posted here.

**Later(er?) edit:** If your tiff file is CYMK, then the result of `imread` is a [MxNx4](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#f25-721031) color matrix, which must be handled differently than usual (because it 3-dimensional).

Comment: Before giving a solution I need to know what your code should do. I didn't figured it out so far; I just found out the source of error. :-) So, let me ask you back: what is the expected result of your function?

Comment: I have a input image a, in which i have to calculate the output image with formula J = c * a^gamma, for gamma = 0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25 and c=const ?

Comment: Well, Phonon's solution might suit you. Or, if it seems simpler and easier to you (I know the Gods of Matlab will punish me for recommending this...) you just make a `for` loop that goes through your gamma values and calls every time your `Funks` function. I'll add the code to my initial comment, alright?

Comment: already Phenon's solution is taking me to another error !!!

??? Error using ==> power
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in ==> Funksioni2 at 13
        J(i, j, :) = (I(i, j) .^ gama) * 2;

Comment: Alright, no panic, let's take it step by step. What is about this function Funksioni2? I didn't see it before. Is this the new version of function that you put the Phenon's code into?

Comment: @CST-Link: what about checking my answer?

Comment: Hi fpe, I recommended the other posted solutions in my main post. Please excuse me, but when I was writing the comment I wasn't aware that you posted also. It was just bad timing. :-)

Comment: @user2287999 Seems like tiff files are kind of peculiar.. When you type `size(a)` (`a` being the result of `imread`) what answer it shows? I'm asking because CYMK tiff are handled differently than the other graphical formats.

Comment: Yes, is the new version of function that Phenon recommended me!

Comment: @user2287999 Last thing to try, then I'm out of tricks in my bag. :-) How about changing in your function `I(i, j) ^ gama` to `double(I(i, j)) ^ double(gama)`?

Comment: im getting this !!!
??? One or more output arguments not assigned during call to 'D:\Matlab\work\Funksioni2.m (Funksioni2)'

i typed in the Command Window this:
a = imread('Lena.tiff');        % Pics or GTFO
v = [0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25];   % Gamma (ar)ray
f = cell(1, numel(v));  % Prepare container for your results
for k=1:numel(v)
    f{k} = Funksioni2(a, v(k), 2);  % Save result from your function
end;

Comment: and Funksioni2 is this file:

function y = Funks(I, gama, c)
[m n] = size(I);
%gama = [0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25];  

% get the number of images to produce
k = length(gama);

% Pre-allocate the output
J = zeros(m,n,k);

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        J(i, j, :) = (double(I(i, j)) .^ double(gama)) * c;
    end
end

Comment: ok, lets take if from the top, again, step by step. Please run `a = imread('Lena.tiff');`. Immediately after, if you type in your Matlab console `disp(size(a))`, what result do you get? After that, if you type in your Matlab console `class(a)`, what it shows?

Comment: 512 512 is the size
and class uint8

Comment: Alright. Now, in your **original** function `Funks` (the one that you written the first time in your post), change the line `J(i, j) = (I(i, j) ^ gama) * c;` to `J(i, j) = uint8((double(I(i, j)) ^ double(gama)) * c);` then save the file with the name `Funks.m`, and type in your console `r=Funks(a,1,1)`. Do you get an error? If not, did it show you something?

Comment: Is not showing me error, but the vector gamma = [0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25];   % Gamma (ar)ray, where to call it ? the result it is showing me the input image without any image processing in it !!!!!

Comment: Don't worry, we'll get to gamma a bit later. First of all we want to make sure that the function works. It's like you checking your car before going to a long travel. :-) If it shows you the same image, that is actually good, because gamma=1 doesn't change your image. Now, type in your console `r=Funks(a,2,1)`. Do you see a change in the image?

Comment: Yes, the output image is white.

Comment: i think that happens because of the parameter 2, when i type r=Funks(1,1.2,1) the output image it has a little white color on it.

Comment: Good. That's a first result: when you set your gamma too high, your image will be "over-exposed". Now, to shorten this, I need you to do 4 things for me: 1) try some gamma values around 1.0, e.g. `r=Funks(a,1.1,1)` and `r=Funks(a,0.9,1)`; please notice the differences in the "brightness" of the image. 2) in the console set your vector `v` to some sensible values, like `v=[0.8, 0.9, 1.1, 1.2]` 3) in the console call your function for those `v` values of gamma like this: `for k=1:numel(v), r=Funks(a,v(k),1); end;` 4) let me know how this works. :-)

Comment: Yes, when i call the function, my image is changing 4 time in the same window(Figure 1). it has the effect of brightness from the vector values !!!

Comment: Alright. So, in conclusion: 1) now the function works; 2) now you know how to call the function multiple times, using `for` statements; 3) crazy values for gamma parameter will destroy your images (2 whitens your image, 20 blows it out of scale apparently); 4) before doing big stuff, verify that your small stuff that you'll use works properly, and check them limits. Is there anything else you'd like to test? :-)

Comment: thank you, i understand the problem now, those vector values that i used are so "crazy values", for that i wasn't satisfied with results. appreciate it. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do makes no sense mathematically. You're trying to assign a *vector* to a *number*. Your problem is not the MATLAB programming, it's in the definition of what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to produce several images `J`, each of which corresponds to a certain `gamma` applied to the image, you should do it as follows:

```
function J = Funks(I, gama, c)
[m n] = size(I);

% get the number of images to produce
k = length(gama);

% Pre-allocate the output
J = zeros(m,n,k);

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        J(i, j, :) = (I(i, j) .^ gama) * c;
    end
end
```

In the end you will get images `J(:,:,1)`, `J(:,:,2)`, etc.

If this is not what you want to do, then figure out your equations first.

Comment: i have to write the operation that takes the input image a, and calculate the output image with formula J = c * a^gamma, for gamma = 0,2,5,8,10,12,15,20,25 and c=const ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would follow:

1) `arrayfun`

```
results = arrayfun(@(i) I(:).^gama(i)*c,1:numel(gama),'UniformOutput',false);
J = cellfun(@(x) reshape(x,size(I)),results,'UniformOutput',false);
```

2) `bsxfun`

```
results = bsxfun(@power,I(:),gama)*c;
results = num2cell(results,1);
J = cellfun(@(x) reshape(x,size(I)),results,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: it looks scary and so advanced to me. Sorry o.O

Comment: @user2287999: it isn't any of the two. it's pretty much doing what the other two SO companions advised.

Comment: ??? Undefined command/function 'bsxfun'.
??? Undefined command/function 'arrayfun'.
 i did it this !!

function y = Det(I, gama, c)
[m n] = size(I);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
       results = bsxfun(@power,I(:),gama)*c;
        results = num2cell(results,1);
        J = cellfun(@(x) reshape(x,size(I)),results,'UniformOutput',false);
    end
end
y = J;

Comment: You don't have to put any loop. Those few lines (one of the approaches) are already doing everything you need, avoiding directly called loops.

Comment: And btw why undefined bsxfun and arrayfun? They are built in Matlab functions!

Comment: idk, maybe version of matlab. I have 7.0.19920 (R14)